# Adjusting for population substructure in heterozygosity values using regression with principal components

Tags: regression, pca, gwas

I'm working on some sample level QC for a large genome wide association study and while reading through the QC documentation for the UK Biobank project, I came across this part, discussing a technique to account for population substructure before flagging samples with unusual heterozygosity.

> **A4 Accounting   for the heterozygosity  bias    explained   by  population  structure**
>
> Heterozygosity (computed  from    either autosomal    or  X-chromosome    SNPs)   is  sensitive   to
>   population    structure   because of  ascertainment   bias:   a   majority    of  SNPs    on  the UK   Biobank    Axiom   > array were    chosen  to  satisfy certain properties  imputation  coverage,    for    example  in European >populations.  Here we describe    the details of  a   regression model    to  adjust  heterozygosity  by accounting   for the effects of  population  structure.
>
> Let   h   denote  the heterozygosity  and let x   be  a   set of  features    correlated  with    ancestry.
>   We    used    the projections onto    the four    major   UK  Biobank principal   components  to   characterise   ancestry,   writing x   =   (x1,    x2, x3, x4) for these four principal    component values.   Consider    the following   model for   heterozygosity  under population structure:
>
> h(x)  =   h0 +    β(x)
>
> where
>
> h(x)  is  the raw heterozygosity, which   depends on  the features    x,   h0  is the ancestry-adjusted   heterozygosity  and β(x)    is  a   bias    term    due to  population  structure.
>
> We    chose   a   quadratic   form    for β(x),   which   includes    all linear  and quadratic   terms   xi
>   and   xi^2 as well    as  all cross   terms   xixj,   and we  estimated   h0 with ordinary    least   squares.    More > specifically,    the bias    was assumed to  have    the following   functional  form:
>
> β(x) =    β11x1^2 +   β22x2^2 +   β33x3^2 +   β44x4^2 +   β1x1 +  β2x2 +  β3x3
>   + β4x4 +  β12x1x2 +   β13x1x3 +   β14x1x4 +   β23x2x3 +   β24x2x4 +   β34x3x4
>
> The fitted value ĥ0 is the ancestry-corrected heterozygosity.

http://www.ukbiobank.ac.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/UKBiobank_genotyping_QC_documentation-web.pdf

From my interpretation, it appears like they are doing a PCA to select the PCs that show the bulk of the population variance and do a regression analysis using the PCs as the regression coefficients and the heterozygosity per sample as the outcome and call the fitted values from the model as the ancestry corrected heterozygosity values.

Coming from an engineering background, I learned regression analysis from a machine learning perspective to produce predictions, so I wanted to ask if there is a statistical reasoning for this implementation or is this just a neat hack?